# EU Blue card applied and travel back to India

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, paperwork, working-visas

I am an Indian expat living in Krakow and my work visa is valid until December 2018. I have already applied for my as well and my dependant's blue card in May. The process for the blue card is currently taking 5-8 months.

The problem is that we have to travel back to India in December to attend a marriage in family, and that is obviously important to be a part of. I will only be able to return in January 2019 when my work visa would have expired.

I would like to know if I have any option to get any visa extension or if I can get the blue card process expedited. Can I travel to India on the basis of the positive decision if I get it before leaving?

Answer (score 1):

No, visas cannot and will not be extended inside the Schengen Area, and to re-enter Schengen (or even board a plane) you need the original blue card.

The simple fact is that without either a valid visa or the original blue card, you're **not** getting back in.

So cancel your marriage visit if you don't receive the blue card in time and cannot get a temporary visa (call the embassy in India to ask about this).